# Externalize configuration files in various Spring Boot applications and deployed on JBoss

Tags: spring-boot, properties, jboss

I have a problem trying to externalize the configuration files of 3 Spring Boot applications.

I need to build 3 wars on a Jboss server and all of them have their configuration files externalized (outside the war packaging). All the configuration files have to be in the jboss/standalone/config/ server path and I want each one to have the name of the application to differentiate them (app1.properties, app2.properties and app3.properties).

The directory path (jboss/standalone/config/) has to be set at runtime for customer requirement reasons, so it can NOT be hardcoded. I establish it by modifying the Jboss standalone.conf.bat file, adding this line:

> set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Dspring.config.additional-location=C:/jboss-eap-7.2/standalone/config/"

But this doesn't work. And it doesn't work because the application only finds the file in the path C:/jboss-eap-7.2/standalone/config/ when its name is application.properties, if I change the name the application doesn't find it.

The problem is that I can't leave that name, since I'm building 3 applications on the same server and each one has a configuration file, so it can't have 3 files with the same name (application.properties) in the same directory .

The solution would be to modify the name of the configuration files, and that is what I have tried by adding the following line in the applications:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@PropertySources({ @PropertySource("classpath:app1.properties") })
public class ApplicationConfig extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

     public static void main(String[] args) {
         SpringApplication.run(ApplicationConfig.class, args);
     }
}
```

However this does NOT work. It only works if the file name is application.properties

Do you know what could cause the error? If not, would you know any other strategy to build a jboss with 3 war and that we can pass each one the path to the externalized configuration file?

Thank you so much